# How can we check existence of element in postgresql scala?

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick, insert-update, upsert

I am new to Scala and Slick. I have a problem with a proper way how to check existence of item in DB(postgresql). So, I need to implement insert if exist and update method. I have done some update but it does not work in a proper way and there is an error occurs.

> ```
> ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint 
> "IDX_COMPETENCE_SID_UID"_ Detail: Key ("SKILL_ID", "USER_ID")=(2, 
> 20198) already exists. [Sanitized]
> ```

```
def update(skillRow: SkillWithVisibility): DBIO[Int] = {
//TODO skill existence check?
selectByIdForUpdateQ(skillRow.id, skillRow.companyId) update skillRow }
```

What is the best way to modify this method to check skill existence and update it if exist?

Comment: Slick exposes `insertOrUpdate` (aka [upserting](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.0/queries.html#upserting)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use insertOrUpdate or write your own if you need to. You can read about it in this [underscore blog post](https://underscore.io/blog/posts/2015/07/14/upsert.html)